# PHP: Date larger than current date

Tags: php, date

I have this code:

```
$curdate = '22-02-2011';

$mydate = '10-10-2011';                     

if($curdate > $mydate)
{
    echo '<span class="status expired">Expired</span>';
}
```

This would echo expired BUT shouldn't because $mydate is in the future and therefore smaller than the $curdate but PHP is looking at JUST the first two numbers 22 and 10 instead of the whole string. How can I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Try converting them both to timestamps first, and then compare two converted value:

```
$curdate=strtotime('22-02-2011');
$mydate=strtotime('10-10-2011');

if($curdate > $mydate)
{
    echo '<span class="status expired">Expired</span>';
}
```

This converts them to the number of seconds since January 1, 1970, so your comparison should work.

Comment: @Cameron don't you find it a little excessive to define a variable in a wrong format and then convert it to another? why not to define it already in the proper format?

Comment: How about if I would like to know the current date is less than 1 month with mydate? How to do that?

Comment: Also, be careful on different time zones, production server might be running on a different default time zone comparing to localhost.

You can change default time zone using : 
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Colombo");

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that your current variables are strings, and not time variables.

Try this out:

```
$curdate = strtotime('22-02-2011');

$mydate = strtotime('10-10-2011');
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$row_date = strtotime($the_date);
$today = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));

if($row_date >= $today){
     -----
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)

Answer (score 2):

```
$currentDate = date('Y-m-d');

$currentDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($currentDate));

$startDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("01/09/2019"));

$endDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("01/10/2022"));

if (($currentDate >= $startDate) && ($currentDate <= $endDate)) {

    echo "Current date is between two dates";

} else {

    echo "Current date is not between two dates";  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the PHP date/time classes to convert these string representations into something you can directly compare using getTimestamp() to compare the UNIX times.

If you're sure all your dates are in this format, you can string slice them into YYYY-MM-DD, and a string comparison will function correctly then.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(strtotime($curdate) > strtotime($mydate))
{
...
}
```

Answer (score -3):

it's VERY simple

```
$curdate = '2011-02-22';
$mydate = '2011-10-10';                     

if($curdate > $mydate)
{
    echo '<span class="status expired">Expired</span>';
}
```

Comment: and what if the OP can't change the date format at the source?

Comment: @jnpcl what a strange whim of him it would be! Why to change a proper format to something else?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: At my work, I have to deal with legacy systems that only give dates as `MMDDYY`.. As much as I'd like to change them to something proper, I can't. Sometimes you're just stuck with a bad format.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: It's anecdotal evidence. The OP did not state that he could change the formatting. Your answer assumes he can change it.

Comment: @jnpcl but hes defining it right in the code. So, he have to define it in the right format already. You're making too big deal of it. Relax, it's not that hard :)

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: It's example code.. It's silly to assume he's going to change a hard-coded variable named `$curdate` every day.