# If date is bigger than.. not working properly in php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: Date larger than current date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082261/php-date-larger-than-current-date)

I have my dates in this format: dd-mm-yyyy

Now according to php, 28-06-2011 is bigger than 01-11-2011

```
$today = date('d-m-Y', time());

if("28-06-2011" > $today ){
     echo "This returns true";
}
```

How can i make this work properly?

Comment: If that date was in the format `YYYY-MM-DD` you could do it the way you described.

Comment: @Tim nope, not even then - it would use only the YYYY portion for the comparison

Comment: @Pekka:  Are you positive? It [seems to be working fine](http://codepad.org/zTBkPy9A) on the tests I tried.

Comment: @Tim indeed! Paint me surprised. I always assumed that strings get auto-cast to int first before being compared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>You can't compare dates like that. They're two strings. PHP will try to interpret them as numbers (taking the first two digits and then failing because of the `-`) and compare those.</strike> Turns out this is not correct. `YYYY-MM-DD` type strings can indeed be compared using `>` and `<`.

So refer to [Col. Shrapnel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7968500/if-date-is-bigger-than-not-working-properly-in-php/7968692#7968692) and change your date format - it makes sense anyway. If you can't do that (because it's a user-input date or whatever),  you can create two [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) objects which, thanks to PHP 5 magic, you can also compare like this:

```
$date1 = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
$date2 = new DateTime('2001-01-01');

if ($date1 > $date2)... // this works
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(strtotime("28-06-2011") > time()) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have my dates in this format: dd-mm-yyyy

That is where you are wrong.
you shouldn't have your dates in this firmat. Have them in **yyyy-mm-dd** and you'll be able to compare them with no problem.

Answer (score -1):

You cant compare date with string.
Create another date item similar to today variable with fixed date of 28-06-2011 and then compare 2 objects.
$datetocompare = date("d-m-Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, 28, 06, 2011));

if($datetocompare>$today) {}
this would then work.

Source: http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score -1):

If you do it that way, you're actually comparing strings, rather than dates. To correctly compare dates, you would need to convert the date values/strings to `time stamps`, you can use the `strtotime` function to accomplish just that.

Here is a link with more info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php