# Comparing dates in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using following code in WordPress to check if articles are posted before 15-09-17  but the problem is if the date is greater than 15 and month is less it still shows the day is greater. For example if $pdate is 28-08-17 and $mydate is 15-09-17 it still return as true.

```
    $pdate  = strtotime(get_the_date("d-m-y"));
    $mydate =   strtotime('15-09-17');
    if ($pdate>$mydate)
    {
    //do something
    }
    else {
    //do something
    }
```

Comment: echo both variables and see which is greater!

Comment: i tried doing that its value is still greater

Comment: pdate is greater than mydate when echoing?

Comment: There might be a very simple fix to this which I am not so sure about. Change the double quotes in `"d-m-y"` to single quotes.

Comment: I hope it may be helpful-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082261/php-date-larger-than-current-date

Comment: Like that-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082261/php-date-larger-than-current-date.I hope It May Be USeful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's interpreting your first numbers (i.e. 28 and 15) as the year.

From the [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) manual:

> If, however, the year is given in a two digit format and the separator
>   is a dash (-, the date string is parsed as y-m-d.

Try using a four digit year so it doesn't parse the date string in an undesirable way:

```
$pdate  = strtotime(get_the_date("d-m-Y"));
$mydate =   strtotime('15-09-2017');
if ($pdate>$mydate)
{
//do something
}
else {
//do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've specified the format of `$pdate` using `d-m-y`; however, `$mydate` follows the format set in `Settings > General`. Make sure the two formats match to have correct comparison.

To clarify, let the code reflect the date format in your setting. Say you want the date in your posts to appear like so: `September 20, 2017`, which is `F j, Y`. Your code will be:

```
$pdate  = strtotime(get_the_date('F j, Y'));
    $mydate =   strtotime('September 15, 2017');
    if ($pdate>$mydate)
    {
    //do something
    }
    else {
    //do something
    }
```

Comment: $mydate will be static and $pdate is post date of wordpress post

Comment: I do realise that, but if date format is set at y-m-d (for example) in your settings, 15 will be interpreted as the year when comparing the two dates.

Comment: Passing a php date string into `get_the_date()` completely overrides the date setting in `Settings > General`. No need to change your date format to reflect settings.

Comment: I know! But were've not used get_the_date for `$mydate` so it takes settings' format. And instead of having to change the settings format (whose effect will also appear in the front end), I've decided to change `&pdate`'s to match settings' format and therefore `mydate`'s.

Comment: In other words, how do you make sure that 15-09-17 is interpreted as September 15, 2017 instead of September 17, 2015 (in case it doesn't follow the settings' format).

Comment: It doesn't take "settings' format"... `strtotime()` is completely independent of Wordpress; it's native to PHP. Your answer will also work, it's just the statement "`$mydate` follows the format set in `Settings > General`" is wrong.

Comment: @Spartacus I see, does that mean that it takes php's default time format (if there were any)?

Comment: There is no "default" time format. `strtotime()` expects a php date string, and outputs a timestamp. More info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: @Spartacus Makes sense, thank you so much for your correction!

Answer (score 0):

With the new update the code that works is as follows:

```
<?php 

$pdate  = get_post_timestamp();
$mydate = time();
if ($pdate < $mydate) {
    echo 'Do something';
} else {
    echo 'Do something else';
}
```

More info at [Wordpress 5.3 - Date/Time Improvements](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2019/09/23/date-time-improvements-wp-5-3/)