# MYSQL - Date stored in different format dd-mm-yy - Cannot retrieve values

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following values.

[image]

As you can see in the picture date is not stored in standard mysql date format.

It is stored in dd-mm-yy

I want to select the rows for which the invoicedate is before 20-09-2017, so it should contain row 13-09-17.

I tried the following query, but it doesn't anything.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `invoices` 
WHERE date_format(invoicedate,'%d-%m-%Y') < date_format(20-09-17,'%d-%m-%Y')
```

Comment: The best is to concert dd-mm-yyyy format into yyyy-mm-dd format and use date as datatype instead of a char or varchar datatype

Comment: Can you use strtotime() in date  check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082261/php-date-larger-than-current-date?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa  this will help you

Answer (score 1):

Use 2017 as the year in your date, and wrap the date in a apostrophes:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `invoices` 
WHERE date_format(invoicedate,'%d-%m-%Y') < date_format('20-09-2017','%d-%m-%Y');
```

Answer (score 1):

In my side the result of `date_format('20-09-2017','%d-%m-%Y')` is null,this might the reason for you.

Try with below(it works fine in my side):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `invoices` 
WHERE invoicedate < STR_TO_DATE('20-09-2017', '%d-%m-%Y');
```

Comment: @vSugumar Updated my answer,it works fine in my side and not sure if it work in your side

Comment: it returns all the rows in the table

Comment: @vSugumar that's weird,when I test in my computer,it only return data that before the   specified date.

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT * 
FROM `invoices` 
WHERE strtotime(invoicedate) < strtotime(20-09-17)
```

Comment: is this helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * 
FROM  `invoices` 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE( invoicedate,  '%d-%m-%Y' ) < STR_TO_DATE(  '20-09-2017',  '%d-%m-%Y' ) 
LIMIT 0 , 30